# In Slack can we toggle message preview when using markdown formatting?

Tags: markdown, slack

This question assumes the option `Preferences > Advanced > Format messages with markup` is checked. It hides the WYSIWYG controls and allows the user to compose Markdown without auto-formatting. I prefer using Slack this way because I know markdown well and end up fighting slack's realtime formatters.

Is there a way to preview my markdown before I send it? Perhaps some hotkey?

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution? It seems there was a hotkey, something like `Cmd+Shift+F` that enabled preview, but it doesn't seems to work now.

Comment: @MaksymChernopolskiy nope, i just started memorizing markdown... and when in doubt i message myself on slack